# Module Shedule Python in Telegram API | Модуль Schedule Питон в Телеграм АПИ

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

https://pypi.org/project/schedule/

Sending a message at a given time does not work, what is the problem, errors do not crash.
Не работает отправка сообщения в заданное время, в чем проблема, ошибок не вылетает.

```
import time
from multiprocessing.context import Process
import schedule


def send_message():
    bot.send_message(370921204, 'Hello')


schedule.every().day.at("14:46").do(send_message)


class Time_reports():
    def packets_to_host():
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)

    def start_process():
        p1 = Process(target=Time_reports.packets_to_host, args=())
        p1.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Time_reports.start_process()
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Хмм.. По идее все должно работать корректно.. А ты отдельно проверял метод schedule? Он так сам работает? Допустим через каждые 30 секунд выводил HelloWorld?

Comment: Запрос на каждую минуту работает. Я ставлю, к примеру, если сейчас 16:27, я ставлю сообщение на 16:30, оно не приходит, видимо оно должно прийти на следующий день, подождем)

Comment: ты лучше потестируй не с днями, а минутами

Comment: С минутами работает, после деплоя, через минуту работает

Comment: ну все тогда, значит нужно ждать день)

Comment: Просто странность в том, что я ставлю по сути время, которое еще не наступило)

Comment: может там еще нужно временную зону настроить? UTC итд...

Comment: В документации ничего не написано, но на Heroku -2 от Киевского, сейчас затестим))

Comment: Нет, не сработало(

Comment: Хмм, очень странно, а сегодня?

Comment: Не работает, не понимаю в чем причина

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была с часовым поясом на хостинге. Код рабочий.